# Study Suggestions Needed - Manipulation of SMBIOS Under Linux

Tags: linux, bios

I've got a laptop (MSI GT72S) which features a manual GPU switch button. It can help me switch between the Nvidia GPU and the Intel one so that the disabled one will be hidden to the OS.

However, this function needs a driver called [SCM](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GT72S-6QE-DOMINATOR-PRO-G.html#down-utility&Win10%2064) which *only* supports Windows. When I press the button under Windows, there will be a pop-up window that asks me to reboot the machine so that it can switch to another GPU.

This is really a PIA to me as I use Linux far more often and every time I need to switch the GPU, I have to reboot into Windows and then reboot again. So I'd like to archive this function under Linux.

It seems that this is implemented by editing a block of the SMBIOS (not sure). When the Intel GPU is enabled, this block will be:

```
Handle 0x0052, DMI type 221, 96 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DD 60 52 00 0D 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 FF FF
                FF FF FF 03 04 FF FF FF FF FF 05 06 FF FF FF FF
                FF 07 08 FF FF FF FF FF 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A
                00 FF FF FF FF FF 0B 00 FF FF 00 00 00 0C 00 00
                09 00 35 10 0D 00 FF FF FF FF FF 0E 00 FF FF FF
                FF FF 0F 00 FF FF FF FF FF 10 11 01 02 02 03 00
        Strings:
                Lan Phy Version
                Sensor Firmware Version
                Debug Mode Status
                Enabled 
                Performance Mode Status
                Disabled
                Debug Use USB(Disabled:Serial)
                Disabled
                ICC Overclocking Version
                UNDI Version
                EC FW Version
                GOP Version
                BIOS Guard Version
                Base EC FW Version
                EC-EC Protocol Version
                Royal Park Version
                BP1.2.2.0_RP03
```

...and when the Nvidia GPU is enabled,

```
Handle 0x0052, DMI type 221, 96 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DD 60 52 00 0D 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 FF FF
                FF FF FF 03 04 FF FF FF FF FF 05 06 FF FF FF FF
                FF 07 08 FF FF FF FF FF 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A
                00 FF FF FF FF FF 0B 00 FF FF 00 00 00 0C 00 FF
                FF FF FF FF 0D 00 FF FF FF FF FF 0E 00 FF FF FF
                FF FF 0F 00 FF FF FF FF FF 10 11 01 02 02 03 00
```

But I haven't touched such stuff before and I don't even know where to start. I have Googled it but few material was found. So I strongly need some suggestions now. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an OEM-defined structure (type 221) that reports status and version info. This information is built by the BIOS during POST, and posted to memory for reading by OS-based management agents (like dmidecode in Linux). Changing that information will not change the underlying configuration.